# Fix Mismatch Between Data And Local In Awk Command

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, locale

I am receiving the following error:

`awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=798) warning: Invalid multibyte data detected. There may be a mismatch between your data and your locale.`

The command I'm running is the following:

`cat file.txt | awk 'length($0)<10000' > output-file.txt`

The weird part is that if I pipe to other commands like `awk '{ sub("\r$", ""); print }'`, it works just fine without an error.

Anyone see why I would get this error? Or, should I just ignore it?

Comment: Run as: `LC_ALL=C awk 'length($0)<10000' file.txt >output-file.txt`

Comment: @Heemayl, if you would like to post this as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make the locale as `C` to use only ASCII character set with single byte encoding, pass `LC_ALL=C` to `awk`'s environment:

```
LC_ALL=C awk 'length($0)<10000' file.txt >output-file.txt
```

Also you don't need to use `cat` as `awk` takes filename(s) as argument(s).

Comment: Since the C locale only works with ASCII charset, will this have the side-effect of stripping non-ASCII data from a file?

Answer (score 1):

I've found three solutions on my machines:

### Change environment variable

This has been answered on the approved one.

Add variable `export LC_ALL=C` to the environment.

### Add parameter (only possible on gawk)

Add `-b` (binary) parameter. Like in:

```
cat file.txt | awk -b 'length($0)<10000' > output-file.txt
```

### Use mawk instead of gawk

You can check if you are using `gawk` or `mawk` implementation on Linux (the first one is installed with a package of the same name on Ubuntu). For Ubuntu you can run

```
sudo update-alternatives --config awk
```

[Source answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/561626/170833)